# Convergence or divergence of improper integral

Tags: integration, analysis, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

I want to check if the following integral converge or diverge.

$\displaystyle{\int_1^{+\infty}\frac{(\ln t)^{\beta}}{t^{\alpha}}\, dt, \alpha ,\beta\in \mathbb{R}}$

$$$$

Do we have to take cases for $\alpha$ and $\beta$ ?

If $0<\beta\leq \alpha-2$ we get $$\ln t\leq t \Rightarrow \left (\ln t \right )^{\beta}\leq t^{\beta} \leq t^{\alpha-2} \Rightarrow \frac{\left (\ln t\right )^{\beta}}{t^{\alpha}}\leq \frac{1}{t^2}$$ and since $\int_1^{\infty}\frac{1}{t^2}\, dt=\left [-\frac{1}{t}\right ]_1^{+\infty}=0+1=1<\infty$ the integral $\displaystyle{\int_1^{+\infty}\frac{(\ln t)^{\beta}}{t^{\alpha}}\, dt}$ converges also, right?

Could you give me a hint for the other cases?

Comment: For $\beta \geq 0$, the behavior depends mainly on $\alpha$ (divergence for $\alpha < 1$, convergence for $\alpha > 1$). For $\beta < 0$ the integral can diverge both in 1 and $\infty$, so I would try to get an equivalent of the integral at 1 and $\infty$.

Comment: For $\beta\geq 0$ and $\alpha >1$ do we show the convergence similar as I did it above? @jvc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\int_1^\infty\frac{\log^\beta(t)}{t^\alpha}dt; \alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{R}$$

Let $t\rightarrow e^x:$

$$\int_0^\infty x^\beta e^{(1-\alpha)x}dx$$

For $\alpha \leq 1$, the integral will be divergent regardless of the value of $\beta$:
$$\int_0^\infty x^\beta e^{(1-\alpha)x}dx\geq \int_0^\infty x^\beta dx\rightarrow +\infty
 $$

For $\alpha > 1$,the integral can be seem like a Laplace Transform, in wich $s=\alpha-1$:
$$\displaystyle\lim_{s\rightarrow\alpha-1}\int_0^\infty x^\beta e^{-sx}dx=\displaystyle\lim_{s\rightarrow\alpha-1}\mathcal{L}[x^\beta]=\displaystyle\lim_{s\rightarrow\alpha-1}\frac{\Gamma(\beta+1)}{s^{\beta+1}}=\frac{\Gamma(\beta+1)}{\left(\alpha-1\right)^{\beta+1}}; \beta>-1$$

Therefore, the integral will converge for $\alpha>1$ and $\beta>-1$. Otherwise, it will diverge.

**Edit:** to prove this without resorting to the Laplace Transform, one may show that:

$$\underbrace{\int_0^\infty x^\beta e^{-sx}dx}_{sx\rightarrow z}=\frac{1}{s^{\beta+1}}\int_0^1 z^\beta e^{-z}dz+\frac{1}{s^{\beta+1}}\int_1^\infty z^\beta e^{-z}dz$$

For the first integral:
$$\int_0^1 z^\beta e^{-z}dz\leq\int_0^1 z^\beta dz=\left[\frac{z^{\beta+1}}{{\beta+1}}\right]^1_0=\frac{1}{\beta+1}$$
Hence, $\beta>-1$ for the integral converge.

For the second integral, let $\beta<N; N\in\mathbb{N}$:
$$\int_1^\infty z^\beta e^{-z}dz\leq\int_1^\infty z^N e^{-z}dz\overbrace{=}^{IBP}1+N\int_1^\infty z^{N-1} e^{-z}dz$$

Which can be further proven by Induction that will also converge.

Comment: In the case of $\alpha>1$ could we do that also in an other way without Laplace Transform ?

Comment: Having now the integral $\int_0^\infty x^\beta e^{(1-\alpha)x}dx$ couldn't we find bounds (upper or lower) to show convergence or divergence? (I mean instead of using the Laplace Transform.)

Comment: I just edited the post with another approach. I'm not sure if it will fully address your question, but that’s my best shot as someone with no formal mathematical background. I hope it helps you. In any case, if you still have questions, I will try my best to answer it.

Comment: Why does the first integral converge only when $\beta>-1$? The fraction can also be negative but a real number, can it not?

Comment: No, it can't. Because when $\beta<-1$, $z^{\beta+1}\rightarrow -\infty$ at $z\rightarrow 0$

Comment: As for your Edit part: We have splitted the integral into a sum of two integrals. We have shown that the first integral converges if $\beta>-1$. Do we not have tocheck the convergence of the second integral also in that case, i.e. when $\beta>-1$ ? Then having shown in that way the convergence for $\beta>-1$ it doesn't mean that the integral diverges when $\beta\leq -1$, we just know the divergence of $\int_0^1 z^\beta dz$. Or do we check that the second integral of the sum diverges for $\beta\leq -1$ ?

Comment: In the case $\alpha>1$ we have the following: 
$$$$ 
For the first integral $\displaystyle{\int_0^1t^{\beta}e^{(1-\alpha)t}\, dt\leq \int_0^1t^{\beta}\, dt=\left [\frac{t^{\beta+1}}{\beta+1}\right ]_0^1}$.  
If $\beta+1> 0 \Rightarrow \beta>-1$ then this is equal to $\displaystyle{\frac{1}{\beta+1}\in \mathbb{R}}$, so the integral $\displaystyle{\int_0^1t^{\beta}\, dt}$ converges and so also the integral $\displaystyle{\int_0^1t^{\beta}e^{(1-\alpha)t}\, dt}$.

Comment: For the second integral $\displaystyle{\int_1^{+\infty}t^{\beta}e^{(1-\alpha)t}\, dt< \int_1^{+\infty}t^{\beta}\, dt=\left [\frac{t^{\beta+1}}{\beta+1}\right ]_1^{+\infty}}$. 

If $\beta+1< 0 \Rightarrow \beta<-1$ then this is equal to $\displaystyle{-\frac{1}{\beta+1}\in \mathbb{R}}$, so the integral $\displaystyle{\int_1^{+\infty}t^{\beta}\, dt}$ converges and so also the integral $\displaystyle{\int_1^{+\infty}t^{\beta}e^{(1-\alpha)t}\, dt}$.

Comment: So we have to cjeck the convergence of the second integral if $\beta>-1$ and the convergence of the first integral if $\beta<-1$, or not?

Comment: Hi, sorry for taking so long to reply. I didn't use the same function in the second integral to show it's convergence. Note that the integral $\int_0^\infty t^\beta dt$ will diverge due to it's upper limit of integration, so we can't use it show our desired outcome. In my edit I've chosen the function $z^Ne^{-z}$, with $N>\beta, N\in \mathfrak{N}$, because for the interval $(1,\infty)$, $z^N,>z^\beta$ for all cases

Comment: I'm not sure if it addresses properly your doubts, but feel free to send me another question and I will try to answer it